# Installing Software in Linux Ubuntu - shotdetect for detecting video shots

Tags: compiler-errors, ffmpeg, makefile, ubuntu-10.04

I have got many errors while installing shotdetect software. some errors were because of the dependencies and that is resolved.Its able to configure perfect but "make" i.e., running make file is throwin this error.
error :  ffmpeg/avcodec.h No such file or Directory
         ffmpeg/avformat.h No such file or Directory

May be its because ffmpeg or shotdetect software versions are different. I tried re-installing the latest (and old ffmpeg) ones but not able to find ffmpeg folder in my /usr/include/ and that is why there is no such file "ffmpeg/avcodec.h".
Please help.

Comment: What happens when you run these commands? 
locate avcodec.h or locate ffmpeg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution..
I made a folder ffmpeg in my /usr/include/ and included all the files from /usr/include/libavcodec.. etc in /usr/include/ffmpeg/.. finally it is working.
Following steps will help installing s/w in ubuntu 10.x and 11.x

Install ShotDetection software

1. Install Dependencies

   sudo apt-cache search gcc
      sudo aptitude install build-essential
      sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavformat-dev pacman libgd2-noxpm-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev cmake libswscale-dev libjasper-dev

2. make a folder named ffmpeg in /usr/include/ and copy essential files

```
cd /usr/include/
sudo mkdir ffmpeg  
sudo cp /usr/include/libavcodec/*  /usr/include/ffmpeg/
sudo cp /usr/include/libavformat/*  /usr/include/ffmpeg/
sudo cp /usr/include/libswscale/*  /usr/include/ffmpeg/
```

3. Download and install shotdetect software

```
    cd /var/www/

   wget http://shotdetect.nonutc.fr/releases/latest.tar.gz
   tar xvzf latest.tar.gz
   cd shotdetect-1.0.86
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
```

4. check in /usr/local/bin/ shotdetect executable file should be there.

Comment: why are you doing `chmod -R ...` on step 2 ? and what does it mean by `0777` ?

Comment: why negative vote here... this s full proof solution for shotdetect. i need xplaination for -tive vote or i dont trust stackoverflow.

Comment: dont do chmod 0777. it gives full access to /usr/include/ just give sufficient permissions to /usr/include/ to copy the folder.

Comment: this is just weird, you do not need to do `0777` to just copy stuffs from `/usr/include/`, I followed the step 2 without putting much attention and mistakenly made `0777` to all my files in `/usr/include/`, which eventually screwed my whole system, and it took a long time to revert back all the contents in `/usr/include` to the previous state, doing `0777` is a *total nonsense*, moreover you are doing `-R`, this is just horrible.

Comment: yes sudo chmod -R s dangerous.. i agree even i realized it now. was jus a newbie that time.